# How to get (matching) data across multiple tables in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Question:** How can I get data which is associated with each other in my controller from separate controllers and models?

**Issue:** I need my @order.seller_id's (which matches a @user.id) and then i need the @user.stripe_token.

So i ultimately need the @user.stripe_token from the correct user_id, which is matched up through the @order.seller_id

The order has a seller_id which is a users id.  This id is the same across all tables that have a user attached to it.  So in order to transfer the money, I need the correct @user the seller_id is associated to

Here's the piece of code i need this for from my orderscontroller:
*(when a order gets updated, the charge gets captured and seller receives commission)  It may not be set up 100% correctly atm but this is the currently where i'm at.*

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
    :amount      => (@order.order_price).to_i * 100,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd',
    :customer => @order.stripe_customer_token,

    })

transfer = Stripe::Transfer.create({
    application_fee_percent: 75
    :currency    => 'usd',
    destination: ---here's where i need the correct @user.stripe_token ---,
    transfer_group: "notes_328324"
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Order class you can do...

```
belongs_to :seller, foreign_key: :seller_id, class_name: 'User'
```

Once you've done this, rails knows about the relationship between Order and User, so you can then do...

```
@order.seller.stripe_token
```